# How to filter WP_User_Query() by role on form submission

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to filter all users by their role when the form gets submitted. I am able to do this within the original $args but when I try adding this query on form submission it does nothing. See my code below;

```
<?php
    $current_page = ( $_GET['paged'] ) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;
    $users_per_page = 100;

    $args = array(
        'number' => $users_per_page,
        'paged' => $current_page,
        'orderby'   => 'user_registered',
        'order'     => 'DESC'
    );

    if( $_POST['membership_status'] ){
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'role'   => $_POST['membership_status']
            )
        );
    }

    if( $_POST['search'] ){
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            'relation'  => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'   => 'first_name',
                'value' => $_POST['search'],
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key'   => 'last_name',
                'value' => $_POST['search'],
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            )
        );
    }

    $users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
?>

<form action="" method="POST" id="status_form">
    <label>
        Search: 
        <select name="membership_status" id="">
            <option value="active">Active</option>
            <option value="suspended">Suspended</option>
            <option value="submitted">Submitted</option>
            <option value="bronze_membership">Bronze</option>
            <option value="silver_membership">Silver</option>
            <option value="gold_membership">Gold</option>
            <option value="platinum_membership">Platinum</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `meta_query` parameter. Simply specify it in the `$args`:

```
if ($_POST['membership_status']) {
    $args['role'] = $_POST['membership_status'];
}
```

For more information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#User_Role_Parameter

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any reason why you would need meta_query? because I have other filters that use it

Comment: @Reece You need meta_query when you are searching for metas that are not supported by the default query args. For example, custom metas.

Comment: Thanks, What about when you are using 'relation'? see my code if you have a minute.

Comment: @Reece The relation is for the query to see if both meta are required or only one of them. You can read more about it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query